# Rounded corners dilation (Image Processing)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I want to perform an Dilation operation while having rounded corners.
Something like this :
[image: Example]

---

**What I tried :**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(test.jpg)
kernel = np.array([[0,1,0],
                   [1,1,1],
                   [0,1,0]], dtype=np.uint8)
img_d = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=45)
```

***Image used : [test.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxhdT.jpg)***
I tried multiple kernels (with different sizes 3x3, 5x5...) but I didn't succeed to get rounded corners.

[image]

**My Question is :** Can we get rounded corners just by changing the kernel  or should we add a further processing step to achieve this ?

> **NOTE :** My goal is not to create a rounded square... I used this example just to explain the idea of getting rounded corners with a
> dilation operation.

Comment: you need _one_ kernel of round shape, with _one_ iteration. your kernels are way too small to make anything approaching round. a 3x3 can at most make diagonal corners, a 5x5 can make a few more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out a way thanks to "Christoph Rackwitz" comment.

The idea is pretty simple.
We need to use a bigger kernel with a circle shape and reduce the number of Dilation iterations.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

kernel = np.zeros((100,100), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(kernel, (50,50), 50, 255, -1)
plt.imshow(kernel, cmap="gray")
```

[image: circle]


And then use this kernel with just one iteration :

```
img = cv2.imread(test.jpg)
img_d = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
plt.imshow(kernel, cmap="gray")
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV also allows you choose a kernel of your shape and size with `cv2.getStructuringElement`. [From this page](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) you can choose either a rectangle, ellipse or cross shaped kernels.

Since you needed rounded corners I chose the ellipse kernel `cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE` of size `25 x 25`:

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
th_img = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  

kernel =  cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(25,25))
img_dil = cv2.dilate(th_img, kernel, iterations=5)
```

Not exactly the result you were hoping for but here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: There are many strange things about OpenCV, but the circle structuring element not being symmetric really bugs me. I didn’t realize their approximation is so poor!

Comment: at 25 pixels diameter, it's got visibly finite precision... it's still wonky though. all the drawing primitives are broken. I tried to open an issue about it but they didn't understand what I was showing them. a line with LINE_AA is no longer the specified thickness. even when thickness=1 and it's pixel-aligned, it's fuzzy and wider than 1... all of that ought to be overhauled by someone who has an eye for detail... I would be inclined but I can't be bothered with all the insane optimization paths that would have to be touched in there.